# TableView freeze

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

I have an array of items and TableView to display them. Item consists of 4 properties. And there is a method which randomly generate items. Initialy, array is empty but in viewDidLoad i have method, which append 100 items to array with delay about 1 second. Array appends until its count about 1_000_000 items. When I start app it freeze.

It's my tableView methods:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return model.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: DealCell.reuseIidentifier, for: indexPath) as! DealCell
        guard model.count != 0 else {
            cell.instrumentNameLabel.text = "no data"
            cell.priceLabel.text = "no data"
            cell.amountLabel.text = "no data"
            cell.sideLabel.text = "no data"
            return cell
        }
        cell.instrumentNameLabel.text = "\(model[indexPath.row].instrumentName)"
        cell.priceLabel.text = "\(model[indexPath.row].price)"
        cell.amountLabel.text = "\(model[indexPath.row].amount)"
        cell.sideLabel.text = "\(model[indexPath.row].side)"
        return cell
    }
```

Function to append array:

```
server.subscribeToUpdate { updates in
            self.model.append(contentsOf: updates)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
```

How to solve this problem? May be to make some counter for "numberOfRowsInSection" equal to 100 and then when scroll to 100th item increase it to 200 etc. Or is there a more concise solution?

Tried to use ReusableCell, but nothing happened.

Comment: Where are you getting the data for *"100 items"* and then about *"1_000_000"* items?

Comment: There is method which generates randomly this items @DonMag

Comment: Does that generation happen off the main thread?  It sounds like you are blocking the main thread. Try dispatching the object generation onto another queue and the reload the table view on the main queue.

Comment: @Paulw11 Yes, I used custom queue: let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "CustomQueue") queue.async { generating items }. But according CPU record CPU and Thread 1 used 100% recourses.

Comment: I would recommend that you use `let queue = DispatchQueue.global(qos:.userInitiated)`.  Is your UI actually frozen or is it simply that there is no data to display until the generation is finished?  Certainly if you were actually fetching this data from a network source rather than generating random data you would implement paging where you only fetched a small number of rows and fetched more rows as required.

Comment: @Paulw11 yes, it’s frozen and there is some data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you are really trying to do here... your code seems like it's just doing a "stress test" or something.

However, to try and help you understand why your app is "freezing" --

Your `for i in 0...dealsCount {` loop will be running *very* fast. As in maybe 1 or 2 ***thousandths*** of a second per 100 iterations. If you are calling `.reloadData()` every 100th time through the loop, your code is trying to update the UI pretty much constantly. That means your UI will appear "frozen."

Here's an example that you may find helpful...

First, we'll add a "status label" and a progress view to display the progress as we generate Deals. We'll update those every 1000th new Deal created.

Second, as we generate new Deals, we'll append them directly to the controller's `var model: [Deal] = []` array (instead of building new arrays and appending them periodically).

Third, we'll only call `.reloadData()`:

- at the first 1,000 Deals
- then at every 100,000 Deals
- and finally after we've generated all 1-million+

As I said, I don't know what you're really doing ... but it is unlikely someone would scroll through the first 1,000 rows before we add the next 100,000 records.

However, you'll find that you can scroll the table **while** the records are being generated... and, after they've all been generated, selecting any cell will jump to the 900,000th row.

Here's how it looks:

[image] [image]

[image] [image]

**Deal Struct**

```
struct Deal {
    var id: Int64 = 0
    var dateModifier: Date = Date()
    var instrumentName: String = ""
    var price: Double = 0
    var amount: Double = 0
}
```

**Simple multi-line label cell class**

```
class DealCell: UITableViewCell {
    let theLabel = UILabel()
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() {
        theLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        theLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.95, alpha: 1.0)
        theLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.addSubview(theLabel)
        let g = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            theLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor),
            theLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
            theLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),
            theLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor),
        ])
    }
    func fillData(_ aDeal: Deal) {
        let i = aDeal.id
        let d = aDeal.dateModifier
        let nm = aDeal.instrumentName
        let p = String(format: "%0.2f", aDeal.price)
        let a = String(format: "%0.2f", aDeal.amount)
        theLabel.text = "\(i): \(nm)\nPrice: \(p) / Amount: \(a)\n\(d)"
    }
}
```

**Demo view controller**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    
    var model: [Deal] = []
    
    let instrumentNames: [String] = [
        "accordion",
        "acoustic guitar",
        "bagpipes",
        "banjo",
        "bass guitar",
        "bongo drums",
        "bugle",
        "cello",
        "clarinet",
        "cymbals",
        "drums",
        "electric guitar",
        "flute",
        "French horn",
        "harmonica",
        "harp",
        "keyboard",
        "maracas",
        "organ",
        "pan flute (pan pipes)",
        "piano",
        "recorder",
        "saxophone",
        "sitar",
        "tambourine",
        "triangle",
        "trombone",
        "trumpet",
        "tuba",
        "ukulele",
        "violin",
        "xylophone",
    ]
    
    let tableView = UITableView()
    let progressView = UIProgressView()
    let statusLabel = UILabel()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        [statusLabel, progressView, tableView].forEach { v in
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            view.addSubview(v)
        }
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            statusLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            statusLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            statusLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            
            progressView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: statusLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            progressView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            progressView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            
            tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: progressView.bottomAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),

        ])

        tableView.register(DealCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "c")
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        
        statusLabel.textAlignment = .center
        statusLabel.textColor = .systemRed
        
        subscribeToDeals()
    }
    
    func updateProgress(currentCount: Int64, futureCount: Int64) {
        
        // update the status Lable and progress bar
        statusLabel.text = "Generated \(currentCount) of \(futureCount)"
        progressView.progress = Float(currentCount) / Float(futureCount)

        // only reload the table if we're at
        //  the first 1_000, or
        //  every 100_000, or
        //  we're finished generating Deals
        
        // if it's the first update
        if currentCount == 1_000 {
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
        // else if we're at an even 100_000
        else if currentCount % 100_000 == 0 {
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
        // else if we've generated all
        else if currentCount == futureCount {
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
        
    }

    func subscribeToDeals() {
        
        let bkgQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "subscribing", qos: .background)
        
        bkgQueue.async{
            
            let dealsCount = Int64.random(in: 1_000_000..<1_001_000)

            for i in 0...dealsCount {
                
                let currentTimeStamp = Date().timeIntervalSince1970
                let timeStampRandomizer = Double.random(in: 50_000...50_000_000)
                let deal = Deal (
                    id: i,
                    dateModifier: Date(timeIntervalSince1970: Double.random(in: currentTimeStamp - timeStampRandomizer...currentTimeStamp)),
                    instrumentName: self.instrumentNames.shuffled().first!,
                    price: Double.random(in: 60...70),
                    amount: Double.random(in: 1_000_000...50_000_000)
                )
                
                // append directly to data
                self.model.append(deal)
                
                // if we're at a 1_000 point
                if i % 1_000 == 0 {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.updateProgress(currentCount: i, futureCount: dealsCount)
                    }
                }

            }

            // we've generated all deals
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.updateProgress(currentCount: dealsCount, futureCount: dealsCount)
            }

            print("Done generating \(dealsCount) Deals!")
        }
        
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return model.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let c = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "c", for: indexPath) as! DealCell
        c.fillData(model[indexPath.row])
        return c
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if model.count > 1_000_000 {
            tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: 900_000, section: 0), at: .middle, animated: false)
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** this is ***Example Code Only!!!*** It is not intended to be, and  should not be considered to be, "production ready."

Comment: Thank you very much for the idea of gradually updating the table! Yes, in fact it is something like a stress test. @DonMag

Answer (score 0):

The code below should solve your problem by unblocking the main thread using DispatchQueue

```
server.subscribeToDeals { deals in
       self.model.append(contentsOf: deals)
       DispatchQueue.main.async {
          self.tableView.reloadData()
       } 
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, its does not work :c